# Non-US-ASCII characters in URL

Tags: html, url, browser, utf-8

I'm trying to write easy image server, will print paths to pictures in `img`-tags on one HTML page. I did it and all was fine before I looked on console of browser. I fount out, some pictures wasn't found with error 404, but files are being searched by back-end code, is working 100%. I considered it in more detail and I saw paths are URL-encoded (I didn't encode) and there are characters like `%A0` or some another, can't be in names of files or folders of site. But no one picture consists of any Cyrillic or any another non-US-ASCII letter was displayed on page. I decided, some UTF-8 chars are consisted of 1-4 bytes and they are divided to many bytes and encoded separately.

1. First I decided to URL-encode on back-end, but all no-ASCII chars
   were encoded like `%FF` (of course, it couldn't to be decoded).
2. Second, I tried to push `%` before hex-encoded chars (`%410` had to
   become Cyrillic `А`), but it decoded two first chars only and third
   was kept undecoded.
3. Third, I tried to escape chars by backslash (`\U410` had to become
   Cyrillic `А`), but every backslash was rewrote to usually slash.
4. Next, I tried to rewrite all backslashes to percent char (`%U410`
   ...), but it gave error 400.

What can I do more to escape non-US-ASCII chars? Help, please!

Comment: Please share a [mcve]: at least wrongly encoded and desired paths…

Comment: The proper way to url-encode any non-ASCII character in a URL is to first charset-encode the character to byte octets, typically using UTF-8, and then percent-encode the resulting octets individually in `%HH` format. So, for instance, Cyrillic `А` in UTF-8 url-encoding is `%D0%90`

Comment: But exactly this was done automatic by browser what caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by python3 script:

```
from sys import argv
s = ""
for i in argv[1]:
    if (i == "/") or (ord(i) > 0xFF):
        s = s + i
    else:
        s = s + "%" + hex(ord(i))[2:]
print(s)
```

First argument — line to URL-encode, output — encoded URL.
I think, it's because non-ASCII characters can not be understood by browser and it gives it native, but when there were ASCII chars, something wasn't escaped and started some voodoo.